# Como fazer funcionar um evento com xamarin.forms e c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, eventos

Quando eu declaro um evento em minha MainPage.xaml, não consigo fazer a implantação. No visual diz que a implantação foi feita com êxito, mas no meu celular fica tudo branco e não dá nem pra navegar nele, até música se estou ouvindo não consigo parar ou avançar. Se eu removo a declaração do evento, aí funciona.
Minha MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Teste1"
             x:Class="Teste1.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackLayout Padding="5,5,0,0">
            <Label Text="Adicionar um Produto" TextColor="Green" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,0">
            <Entry x:Name="txtNome" Placeholder="Nome do produto" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Entry x:Name="txtCategoria" Placeholder="Categoria do produto" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small" />
            <Entry x:Name="txtPreco" Placeholder="Preço do produto" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                    HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small" />
            <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" Text="Adicionar/Atualizar Produto" 
                    Clicked="btnAdicionar_Clicked" FontSize="Small"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10,5,10,0">
            <ListView x:Name="listaProdutos" BackgroundColor="Aqua" SeparatorColor="Blue">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Clicked="OnAtualizar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Atualizar" />
                                <MenuItem Clicked="OnDeletar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Deletar" IsDestructive="True" />
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10,10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Nome}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Categoria}" TextColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Preco}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

E o meu MainPage.xaml.cs com o evento:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private async void btnAdicionar_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPageModal());
        }
    }
```

O que passa é o seguinte: Às vezes quando eu starto o projeto sem a declaração do evento, a tela do meu smartphone fica toda branca, desligo a aplicação pelo VS e abro pelo cel diretamente e funciona. Quando porem, deixo o evento habilitado, a tela fica branca. Desligo a aplicação pelo VS e quando vou pelo Cel direto, dá essa mensagem: Teste1.Android parou. Não sei mesmo o que pode ser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu método chama-se `btnAdicionar_OnClicked` enquanto que a chamada do evento `Clicked` do botão está apontando para `btnAdicionar_Clicked`

Faça a correção que seu conteúdo aparecerá no dispositivo/emulador

Comment: Nem percebi isso, fiquei tão dentro da casinha que passou batido isso. Estou testando, é que é muito lento tudo aqui. De qualquer forma, obrigado por me fazer sair da casinha.

Comment: Beleza. E depois estude [PRISM](https://github.com/angelobelchior/prism-xamarin-forms/wiki). Fará você sair ainda mais da casinha.